# Retagging Perl 5 to the standard Stack Overflow version convention with a hyphen

Tags: discussion, retag-request

History & Background: Perl is a language; perl is an interpreter. Perl 5 is the fifth version of Perl. Perl 6 was set to replace Perl 5. It was so different that the community split such that "Perl" was no longer "a language", and **the language split to "Perl 5"** and "Perl 6". Lastly, in order to eliminate confusion "Perl 6" was renamed "Raku" and divorced from the community. It's now marketed as a *totally* different language. The next version of Perl is Perl 7.

Currently Perl is tagged somewhat uniquely,

- [perl5.34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.34), [perl5.32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.32), etc..

This is because at one point iirc, we had [perl5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5), and [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6), and it was weird to have [perl5-5.34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5-5.34) so they just truncated that to [perl5.34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl5.34).

I'm suggesting we migrate this now to the more standard Stack Overflow convention of

- [perl-5.34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-5.34)
- [perl-5.32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-5.32)

This is what you'd find with other language like Python, Ruby, and PHP, all of which follow the `[language-version]` form. This proposal is just to treat Perl the same as the other language, in style. It changes nothing and just follows the social convention on *every* other language on the site.

---

Note, Perl has been on Version 5 since 1994. It seems we would want something more atomic than just `perl` or `perl-5`, as there are still [new features being developed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68007873/124486). You're talking about 1.7 years per version, right now if there is a tag for every major version of the language (even number with tags from `perl-5.0` - `perl-5.32`).

Comment: Is there any harm in keeping them the way they are?

Comment: Yeah, I (or any mod) can do this rename easily, with no friction whatsoever. We just need to see a bit of community support, since it's really one of those "six one way, half a dozen the other" kinds of things. In other words, neither way is really "right" or "better" than the other; it all comes down to preference.

Comment: I see no need to have any `perlx.xx` tags.  Plain `perl` is sufficient.

Comment: @oguzismail No, it's a name. I can't see it hurting anything regardless. However, it's unique, and violates a convention. I can't think of any other example where the language name and the major semvar sit together, rather than the language name being separated from the version with the hyphen. "Perl5" isn't a thing. And "Perl7" won't be a thing a either. It's Perl: it comes in 5.x and 7.x

Comment: @toolic there are new features introduced with minor point releases, and some questions are specific to them. Look at this question I just asked for example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68007873/124486

Comment: *In general*, toolic's sentiment is a very important one. We want to use version-specific tags *very* sparingly. It does seem extremely rare that there would really be a need for "point" version tags. Major version tags are kind of a necessary evil, but it is hard to believe that there would be enough changes between minor versions to necessitate a tag. But, if some language/tool/ecosystem prefers to do the opposite of Chrome and keep the same major version number for a long time, then I guess it would follow naturally that the minor versions would introduce major features.

Comment: @CodyGray For what it's worth, Perl has been on Version 5 since 1994. It seems obvious to me you may want something more atomic. You're talking about 1.7 years per version, right now if there is a tag for every major version (even numbers from 5.0 - 5.32). Again this isn't radical, it's just also how python, ruby, and php work. This proposal would treat Perl the **same** way following the convention we already have.

Comment: I haven't found any reason to have version specific tags, much less point version specific tags. Features in many point versions of software would still be there. Also, your question answers itself via tags. If you want  to know which version of perl introduced a feature, how would you also know which version did? Tags are about the question, not about the answers.